# PHPのモジュールモードに該当するものは、Pythonでは何に該当するのでしょうか？

Tags: python

**Q1.PHPのモジュールモードに該当するものは、Pythonでは何に該当するのでしょうか？**
・PHPには「モジュールモード」と「CGIモード」があるのですが、Pythonで言うところの「CGI」と言うのは、PHPの「CGIモード」と同じ意味でしょうか？
・例えば、「Python」と「mod_wsgi」の組み合わせをApacheで動かしても、CGIで動かしていることになるのでしょうか？

---

**Q2.「cgi」「wsgi」「mod_wsgi」の違い**
・wsgiは、cgiの一種？
・mod_wsgiは、wsgiの一種？

・例えば.confファイルに下記のように記述した場合、それぞれ意味は異なる？

> AddHandler cgi-script .py 
>   AddHandler wsgi-script .py

---

**Q3.デーモンモード**
・WSGIDaemonProcessと記述すると、デーモンモード (Apacheとは別のプロセス)で動作する、と書いてあったのですが、これは分類すると何に該当するのでしょうか？
・wsgiの一種？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1.PHPのモジュールモードに該当するものは、Pythonでは何に該当するのでしょうか？

mod_python が近いかもしれません。
mod_pythonの後継がmod_wsgiといって良いでしょう。
mod_wsgiが誕生してからはmod_pythonは使われなくなった、と記憶しています。

> ・PHPには「モジュールモード」と「CGIモード」があるのですが、Pythonで言うところの「CGI」と言うのは、PHPの「CGIモード」と同じ意味でしょうか？

はい。CGIの規格にそった入出力インターフェースを備えた実行可能ファイルはCGIと呼んで良いでしょう。
この場合、 `*.py` ファイルが実行可能で、ブラウザからのリクエストを標準入力経由で受け取って、標準出力にブラウザへの応答を返すことになります。

> ・例えば、「Python」と「mod_wsgi」の組み合わせをApacheで動かしても、CGIで動かしていることになるのでしょうか？

いいえ。その言い方でいくと、mod_pythonの方が近いです。
mod_wsgiの場合は、wsgi規格([PEP-3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/))にそったインターフェースを備えたPythonコードをApacheのmod_wsgi経由で起動することになります。

> Q2.「cgi」「wsgi」「mod_wsgi」の違い
>   ・wsgiは、cgiの一種？

いいえ。wsgi規格のインターフェースを実装したPythonスクリプトです。
なので、CGIではありません。
拡張子は `.wsgi` となっていても、中身はPythonスクリプトです。
このスクリプトは `application` というモジュールグローバルな変数を提供する必要があります。
applicationはWSGI規格に沿ったAPIを実装し、WSGIの通信プロトコルに従ってデータの入出力を行います。

> ・mod_wsgiは、wsgiの一種？

はい。
正確には、「Apacheプロセスから、WSGIインターフェースを備えたPythonのプログラムと通信するために使用する、Apacheのモジュール」がmod_wsgiです。

> ・例えば.confファイルに下記のように記述した場合、それぞれ意味は異なる？
>
> AddHandler cgi-script .py 
>   AddHandler wsgi-script .py

異なります。
これを定義したセクションで、 `.py` ファイルをどのハンドラーで動作させたいかを決定するために使用します。上記のように2種類同時に設定できるのかな？wsgiとして使うのであればAddHandlerではなくWSGIScriptAliasで指定したほうが設定が簡潔でよいです。
http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAlias.html

> Q3.デーモンモード
>   ・WSGIDaemonProcessと記述すると、デーモンモード (Apacheとは別のプロセス)で動作する、と書いてあったのですが、これは分類すると何に該当するのでしょうか？
>   ・wsgiの一種？

wsgiです。
WSGIDaemonProcessを指定しない場合と、指定した場合とでデーモンプロセスの起動方法が異なります。
デーモンプロセスはどちらにしても使われるし、インターフェースはwsgiです。
WSGIDaemonProcessを指定しない場合、起動されたデーモンプロセスは全てのアプリケーションで使い回されます。WSGIDaemonProcessを指定した場合、アプリを提供するユーザー毎に異なるデーモンプロセスを使用します。つまり、共用サーバー等で複数のユーザーがwsgiアプリを動かしたい場合に、セキュリティーの向上やクラッシュ時の影響範囲などをユーザー単位に抑えるために指定するオプションです。
http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Comment: 詳細解説ありがとうございました。おかげで疑問が解決しました。ただ一点、「wsgiとして使うのであればAddHandlerではなくWSGIScriptAliasで指定したほうが設定が簡潔でよい」の意味が分かりませんでした。どういう意味でしょうか？　私の認識では、AddHandlerを使用すると「拡張子でwsgi指定できる」ので便利、WSGIScriptAliasだと一度に複数設定できないので面倒と思っていたのですが…。そもそもWSGIScriptAliasはどういう時に利用するのでしょうか？　実際のURLアクセス先とは異なるファイルで処理したい時に使用するものではない？

Comment: WSGIアプリを作る場合、URL毎に異なるPythonスクリプトを指定することはあまりない前提で書いていました。1つのエントリーポイント(WSGIの場合、*.wsgi の application 変数)で全てのURLを受け取って、URLのパス等をみて適切な処理に振り分ける「ルーティング」処理を提供するイメージです。PythonのWebアプリケーションフレームワーク(WAF)は殆ど全てこのように実装されています。Django, Flask, Bottle, 等々ですね。ルーティング機能だけ使いたければ https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebDispatch が使えます。

Comment: なるほど。「ルーティング」処理を考慮した話なのですね。＞​PythonのWebアプリケーションフレ‌​ームワーク(WAF)は殆ど全てこのように‌​実装されています。参考になりました